# object references an unsaved transient even using CascadeType.All

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know that there are many question about this topic, however I could not solve my problem even adding the `CascadeType.ALL` .

I have a two tables called UserMenu and MenuItem (there are one-to-many relationship)

- UserMenuDTO:

```java
@Entity
@Table(...)
@EntityListeners(AuditableListener.class)
public class UserMenuDTO implements Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column("...")
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userMenuDTO", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<MenuItemDTO> menus = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn("..." )
    private QrCodeDTO qrCodeDTO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("...")
    private UserDTO userDTO;
```

- MenuItemDTO:

```java
@Entity
@Table("...")
@EntityListeners(AuditableListener.class)
public class MenuItemDTO implements Auditable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    // ...
    @Column("...")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    private MenuPriceDTO menuPriceDTO;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "...")
    private UserMenuDTO userMenuDTO;
```

- Here is the code where I am adding the menuitem to usermenu:

```java
public static void addMenuItemToUserMenu(UserMenuDTO userMenuDTO, MenuItemDTO menuItemDTO){
        userMenuDTO.getMenus().add(menuItemDTO);
        menuItemDTO.setUserMenuDTO(userMenuDTO);
    }
```

- When I am inserting new menu item to userMenu list, I am getting this error:(**cascadeType.ALL has no effect**)

```java
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - 
save the transient instance before flushing: ...MenuItemDTO;
```

If I save the MenuItem just before the saving the userMenu, everything is fine. I just want to save all items in one statement.

How can i solve this issue?

- **Update (details for persist operation)**

```java
public void persist(){
    UserMenuDTO userMenuDTO = ; // this is from database via userid;
    MenuItemDTO newMenuItemDTO=; // created from request body
    Relation.addMenuItemToUserMenu(userMenuDTO, newMenuItemDTO);
    userService.saveUserMenuDTO(userMenuDTO);
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService{
    @Override
    public void saveUserMenuDTO(UserMenuDTO userMenuDTO) {
        userMenuRepository.save(userMenuDTO);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface UserMenuRepository extends JpaRepository<UserMenuDTO, Long> {
}
```

Comment: please share the complete code where you are persisting the userMenuDTO in database.

Comment: @Naqi, I added the details, please look at the  "Update (details for persist operation)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your `persist` method, the problem is with new `menuItem` object, as it is not attached to the persistence context (in other words it is transient) and you are assigning this transient object to an existing `userMenuDTO` instance fetched from database, this instance fetched from database is attached to the current spring persistence context. So in order to update the list of `menus` of this already persisted object you have to persist the newly created `menuItem` first, then add this persisted `menuItem` to the `menus` list and then finally save the `userMenuDTO`.
`CascadeType.ALL` would work if both the `userMenuDTO` and `menuItemDTO` instances were newly created and you were saving them to database for the first time.

Comment: "CascadeType.ALL would work if both the userMenuDTO and menuItemDTO instances were newly created" that is the new for me, thank your for your answer